# Handling offline data in a web app

Tags: angular, ngrx

Current Stack: Angular 1.6, BreezeJS (to handle offline/online), .net web api, azure sql

Moving to Stack: Angular 5, NgRx (to handle offline/online), .net core Web API, Azure SQL

**Background:** 
I have a web application that has to work offline/online.  While users are in a connected environment, I use web workers to pull down the most recent data for the projects that they are working on and store that data in local storage.  When they go offline, I push/pull data from that local storage to allow the user to work offline.  Right now, the system is built using Angular 1.6 and BreezeJS handles the metadata entities while offline and the subsequent syncing once back online.  This has worked well because BreezeJS does a great job handling all the offline metadata and subsequent syncing pretty transparently and consistently.

I need to upgrade the system to Angular 5 and I want to remove BreezeJS from the stack (mainly because they dont have a typescript update built for Angular and there doesnt seem to be any plan to create one) but I'm not sure how to handle the offline data and the syncing of offline data to online.  The plan I have currently has NgRx take the place of BreezeJS.

I was thinking of using Service Worker to dump requests to a locally stored queue when offline while updating the current store (using ngrx via a distinct action that will denote the record as unconfirmed) no matter what.  Then when the user comes back online, I run the queue of requests and then update the user's local store as responses come in as normal.  I would also update my web workers so that they push actions upon data retrieval that update the ngrx store which then subsequently dumps its contents to local storage so that it's ready for offline use when that need arises.

**Question:** 
I've realized that I'm essentially forcing NgRx to work both offline/online. Is this good usage of the NgRx library or is this taking that library out of context and using it for something that it was never intended for?

Is there an existing production ready and maintained library that is built to handle offline data and syncing in Angular applications?

THanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I understand that Breeze *does* work with Angular v2+. See this link: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge2.angular

Comment: And regarding ngRx, no the offline scenario is not supported out of the box. There have been added libraries such as this: https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Comment: Regarding handling offline data in Angular, have you looked at service workers? See this link: https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-go-offline-with-angular-service-worker-a3cc5dabc4d5

Comment: @DeborahK - Yeah, I saw that bridge but if I used breeze I would have wanted it supported by the group that created the original version.  That's why I wanted to move away from it.  I am using service workers to handle caching of my resources and also to direct requests to offline storage if there is no network connectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoa. Much that is wildly incorrect here.

BreezeJS works great with all versions of Angular. It was re-coded in TypeScript and is now maintained as a TypeScript library. We use it extensively in our practice, building large, enterprise apps in the latest Angular versions. And it is maintained by its original authors.

I ought to know. I’m a founder and the current president of IdeaBlade, the makers of Breeze.

I also know a lot about ngrx. You can serialize the state of the store and restore it but it won’t be trivial to do so and isn’t as easy as with the Breeze entity cache. You could try capturing the stream of actions and replaying them. That will be fraught with difficulty too.

You do not sound like someone who has tried ngrx to manage entities. That is a daunting task for any but the smallest entity models. You better study a bit before you take that leap. I say this as someone who is pioneering a library to make ngrx entity management easier (lookup ngrx-data).

But the most important barrier IMO is the utter lack of support for entity relationships in ngrx or redux, something essential to relational entity models and something which is one of the Breeze core strengths.

If you are used to Breeze, look very, very carefully before you ditch it.

Comment: Sorry Ward, I didn't want it to sound like I was knocking breeze for anything.  I love the library and use it in pretty much all my angularjs projects.  But, I didn't see a mention of re-writing the library in Typescript anywhere on the [site](http://breeze.github.io/doc-main/) and the [angular 2 bridge](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge2.angular) has been in 1.0 beta since November.  I didn't want to use it in this new production app and then find out that it's not being actively maintained and get myself in a bind as a result.

Comment: And yes, I am new to ngrx.  I noticed the excessive amount of boiler plate and that's why I mentioned in an comment above about how I am following the angular-ngrx-data project that you and John Papa are working on.  Unless I misunderstand how John lays it out, entity caching is one of the goals of that library which would address the offline challenges I am facing.  Not to mention, I could try to help out with contributing to the library as I use it.  I also like that it supports a specific architecture for unidirectional flow.

Comment: No problem, Jake. It's really OUR fault for falling down in the product announcements department. We haven't touched the site in forever.

The reason: we've been really busy USING Breeze in our work and not paying sufficient attention to good folks like you. It's my job personally to do something - anything - about this. And I plan to take it up over the next weeks.

Comment: Re: ngrx-data - Inspired by your comment here, today I added two actions and a selector to facilitate exporting and importing the ngrx-data cache (see alpha.13).

As it happens, there's another ngrx-friend library devoted to exporting/importing chunks of store state to local storage. It may be relevant too.
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

I also suspect the main contributors have some plans in this area for v6. 

That said, as much fun as I'm having with ngrx, it ain't Breeze.

Comment: P.S. I know the Angular 2 Bridge is still listed as beta. But it's the one we use and we'd be dead meat without it. I'll ask Marcel about moving it to v.1

Comment: The Angular 2 Bridge has been out for a while and we've used it in many projects. The one that's in beta is the updated bridge that uses the new HttpClient service instead of the old Http service. I've left it in beta just in case there are some issues, but we've successfully upgraded to it in our own projects and so far no issues. I was actually just thinking about making it officially v1 the other day. I will try to do that this week.

Answer (score 1):

Ngrx can be used offline, just store your state in the browsers database the indexedDB using a library like idb.js. You can also load slices of your data dynamically with lazloading. Everything is done in effects init method when loading the Effects forFeature with the modules, here is a link to answer your question with example code [Is the ngrx store persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037908/is-the-ngrx-store-persistent/49041308#49041308).
Ngrx is regularly updating and they have plans for PWA and data sync and much more

Comment: The link you included had a pretty interesting way of handling offline data.  I may give that a go.  For right now, I am giving [angular-ngrx-data](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data/blob/master/docs/introduction.md) a shot.  It's made by John Papa and the same guy that made Breeze (Ward Bell) so I trust what they are trying to do and since it significantly reduces boiler plate code, it will probably be easier to configure to work using the points made by the link you included.