# Is the ngrx store persistent?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

Is the ngrx store persistent?  In other words can we close the browser reopen it, and retrieve state that was added to the [ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform)?

Comment: Did it work like you describe when you tried it?

Comment: The [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f97ICOaekNU&t=14s) I was watching described it as a client side database, so I thought perhaps it could be used in place of pouchdb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently ngrx/store doesn't support such functionality. But you can maintain state by using a library like [ngrx-store-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-persist) to save data to the browsers indexedDB, localStorage or WebStorage. This library automatically saves and restores  ngrx/store's data. You just need to add redux keys that you want to store in the config (see "Usage" section).

Comment: Is there any better way to do this in now?
The recommended library hasn't been updated since 2019, and issues are left unanswered.

Comment: To be honest, if the browser is refreshed, it should just retrieve any data from the DB? 
This ensures that the data is always current. 
I would be wary of persisting NgRx data, in localStorage?

Answer (score 3):

The [nrxg/store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) is in memory only.  To manage state via the browser with something like pouchdb [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) can be used.  [More here](https://gonehybrid.com/a-beginners-guide-to-using-ngrx-in-an-ionic-2-app-part-2/).

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain state by using a library like idb.js to save data to the browsers indexDB, then by using the ngrx effect you can have an init effect to reload the state back when webapp loads. here is a example code let say I want to reload selected language. the effect would be:

```
 @Effect()
  init$: Observable<Action> = defer(() => {
    return from(storageDb.readData('app', Lang.ActionType.LANG_KEY)).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        const tmpData = data ? data.state : {dir: 'rtl', selected: 'ar'};
        this.translate.setDefaultLang(tmpData.selected);
        return new Lang.LanguageInit(tmpData);
      })
    );
  });
```

the storageDb.readData is a wrapper for idb to load data by key, the effect will kick in when effects are getting loaded it will get the data from the indexdb and if it does not find any sets default value then dispatchs an Action. ngrx best practices is to use promises in effects not in reducers since loading the data is async operation, then in your state reducer you can catch the Action like so:

```
case lang.ActionType.LANGUAGE_INIT: {
      return {...state, ...action.payload};
}
```

Using it in this way you can slice your states save them and loaded them even when lazyloading.

Comment: How would you handle the storing of sensitive data? Is there a encryption capability that you could leverage with say a JWT?

Comment: You can create a service that encrypts and decrypts data using a per user key stored in the JWT, all action needs to be executed in the init effect method to avoid async error.One more thing every time the state changes you will need to encrypt it and save in the reducer, but for best practice and to handle save errors properly best do handle it in an effect action